# How to merge column from b-table if some of row item value is empty?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

Im creating a table using b-table from bootstrap vue. All of the data from the data table

[screenshot of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9jfh.png)

I need to merge that red bordered column if the value is empty. Can we do that stuff using available slot from bootstrap table or something else?

I'm currently stuck

Comment: No, rows don't have a slot. The only option you have is using `<b-simple-table>`, doing a `<v-for>` over the rows and switch what's being rendered based on your row value. But this also means whatever else you're using from `<b-table>` (filtering, sorting, etc...) will need to be manually implemented as well.

Comment: On the other hand, If i had to do this, I'd have a look at how rows are actually rendered in `<b-table>` component. Extending it and overriding the part responsible with rendering the row, without breaking anything else, might just work, if you know what you're doing. In order to do this, you should be familiar with render functions, as most BV components don't use templates.